# Use multiple languages at once for the dictionary?

Tags: firefox

So, I speak and write both english and german. Every time I write in the language currently not selected in the dictionary, (nearly) every word gets a red underline. Is there a way to select multiple languages at once and if not, are there "hybrid" dictonary files which would simply combine the contents of the german and english dictonarys into a single file?

Answer (score 3):

## Use [hunspell-merge](https://code.google.com/p/hunspell-merge/downloads/list) tools.

## [OpenOffice dictionaries](http://download.services.openoffice.org/files/contrib/dictionaries/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Uhm, does firefox use the same file format for dictionarys as openoffice?

Comment: @Andalur uncompress *.dic, *.aff; archive *.zip; XPInstall *.xpi; OpenOffice *.oxt -> hunspell-merge convert to
 -> uncompress *.dic, *.aff; archive *.zip; XPInstall *.xpi; Use XPInstall.

Comment: I don't understand...

Comment: @Andalur You can use different of dictionaries including OpenOffice. Then the `hunspell-merge` to make one multilingual dictionary.